# Can Azure B2C users be given permissions to an app reg in an AAD tenant via AAD groups

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

We have an AAD tenant with users.  We have a web app backed by an AAD app reg that permissions user access (via an enterprise application, application roles and mapped AAD groups).

We would like to expose this application to external users via an Azure B2C tenant so that we can manage external users separately.  We know that we could provision guest users into AAD, but we have chosen not to do that because we are likely to have many groups of external users from different organisations.

We have setup an Azure B2C tenant (from our AAD tenant).  However, we are struggling to get B2C users to be able to be added to AAD groups created.  Is this possible?

Note that the AAD app reg is an existing production application that we would like to disrupt as little as possible.  The app reg was created as a single tenant app reg.  Does this need to change?

Any other way we can achieve what we are trying to do (without creating AAD guest users?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t add B2C users to the AAD group that hosts your organisation. These are two separate tenants and completely isolated.

You need to create a new app registration in B2C, configure your application against it and then add AAD as an identity provider to B2C. That will allow your app to be accessed by both AAD and B2C.

Another option would be more complex, but less disruption, is to configure your app to trust both AAD and B2C.

Comment: thanks Jas.  How would i go about configuring the 2nd option?  Doesn't that just mean that i would need to have 2 app regs and 2 configuration sections in the appsettings.json.  Wouldn't this mean that the security would be completely separate for both?

Comment: Yes, this is why I wouldn’t advise it. Fairly custom setup.